# Linq to Entities and reusable logic

Tags: linq-to-entities

if I have a a class represented by a table in a database

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar1 {get; set;}
    public string Bar2 {get; set;}
}

class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

public enum FooDataStatus {Bar1Missing, Bar2Missing, Bar1And2Missing, Complete}

public class MappedFoo
 {
    public string Bar1 {get; set;}
    public string Bar2 {get; set;}
    public FooDataStatus DataStatus ... property or method ...
}
```

I would like to be able to reuse logic to return the FooDataStatus for an individual instance of MappedFoo, and also for iqueryables such that I can get a count of the number of records within the database having each FooDataStatus without passing all records from the database.

```
int completedRecords = (From f in DataContext.Foos
                        ....magic goes here ...
                        ).Count(d=>d==FooDataStatus.Complete);
```

*please note* this is a simplified version of what I am after, but all logic has easily mapped sql equivalent operators, but complex enough that repeating the logic doesn't seem wise.

```
(From f in DataContext.Foos
 where f.Bar1!=null && f.Bar1!="" && f.Bar2!=null && f.Bar2 != "").Count();
```

How can I create a more reusable set of logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using (and I would love any hints on how to improve things, *in particular* the DataStatus get property accessor)> I am happy to mark as answer improvements on below:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Bar1 {get; set;}
    public string Bar2 {get; set;}
}

public class MappedFoo : IFoo
{
    public string Bar1 {get; set;}
    public string Bar2 {get; set;}
    public FooDataStatus DataStatus { get { return CalculateRecordStatusOption.Compile()(this);}}
    public static Expression<Func<IFoo, FooDataStatus>> CalculateRecordStatusOption =
        r =>
            (r.Bar1 == null || r.Bar1 == "")
                ? FooDataStatus.Bar1Missing
                :(r.Bar2 == null || r.Bar2 == "")
                    ? FooDataStatus.Bar2Missing
                    : FooDataStatus.NoneMissing;
}

interface IFoo
{
    string Bar1 {get; set;}
    string Bar2 {get; set;}
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            var emptyRecordCount = context.Foos
                .Select(MappedFoo.CalculateRecordStatusOption)
                .Count(f=>f == FooDataStatus.NoneMissing);
```